# Undefined variable: table when login using laravel5.2

Tags: laravel-5

When I try to login, I get this error

> ErrorException in ActivationRepository.php line 41: Undefined
>   variable: table

but user get logged successfully, this was working fine before, can you please look at this, what could be the issue?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide full code?

Comment: Please Provide your code

Comment: Which code you need,i am using basic scaffolding for authentication. @DharmeshRakholia

Comment: ActivationRepository class code

Comment: Here is the code https://kopy.io/dupRE,look at line 41 and 42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,you need to modify your ActivationRepository class.

Change this

```
private function regenerateToken($user)
    {
        $token = $this->getToken();
        $this->db->table($table)->where('user_id', $user->id)->update([
            'token' => $token,
            'created_at' => new Carbon()
        ]);
        return $token;
    }
```

To

```
private function regenerateToken($user)
    {
        $token = $this->getToken();
        // $this->table refers to 'user_activations',btw you can pass table name manually although not recommended.
        $this->db->table($this->table)->where('user_id', $user->id)->update([
            'token' => $token,
            'created_at' => new Carbon()
        ]);
        return $token;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create ActivationFactory.php

Steps

mkdir app/Factories

code

rote.php

```
Route::get('user/activation/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@activateUser')->name('user.activate');
```

ActivationFactory.php

Add here Your codes

Please Check This link For Example

http://jimfrenette.com/2016/07/laravel-user-registration-with-email-activation/